# Does uniform convergence of a subsequence imply uniform convergence of the sequence? If so, how to show this?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let us suppose to have a series ${f_N} ({N\in\mathbb{N}})$ such that, for each $N$, $f_N: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.
Besides, I know that $f_N$ is continuous for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f=L^2\text{-}\lim_\limits{N\to\infty}f_N$.

I would like to show that $f_N$ uniformly converges to $f$. First, consider the sequence $\left(f_N\right)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$. 
I am told that in order to show that $f_N$ uniformly converges to $f$, it suffices to prove that:
$$\text{"a subsequence of }(f_N)_{N\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ converges uniformly to } f"$$

Why is that true? Could you please explain such a statement/give a reference about that?

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question with the information you have provided. What other assumptions on $f_n$ are available?

Comment: I do not know whether it is an important information: I am also told that $f_N$ is continuous for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Anyway, I edit my question @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: You did not say what you mean by $f=\lim f_N$. What type of convergence is this? If this is point-wise convergence you cannot prove uniform convergence from  it.

Comment: it is convergence in $L^2$. Sorry, I have added this as well on my question right now

Comment: That makes it much worse. You cannot prove this result.

Comment: Suppose I were able to show that a subsequence of $(f_N)$ uniformly converges to $f$. Would be this enough to show that $f$ is continuous? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: You forgot to say what exactly you are trying to prove. You can  prove that $f$ is a.e. equal to a continuous function under the given hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. Short version: you can join a uniformly convergent and a pointwise but not uniformly convergent sequence with the same limit in one sequence and generate a counterexample.

Now let us explicitly write down a counterexample. We choose
$$ f_n(x)= \sqrt{x^2+\frac 1n} \quad\mbox{for even }n\qquad\mbox{and}\quad f_n(x)=|x|+\frac xn \quad\mbox{for uneven }n$$
Then we have $f_n(x)\to|x|=:f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. The convergence $f_{2n}\to f$ is also uniform. However,
$$\sup\{f_n(x)-f(x):x\in\mathbb R\}=\infty,$$
So the whole sequence doesn‘t converge uniformly.

Comment: I will include the counterexample in a second.

Comment: It sounds strange to me, since on the book I am referring to it is said that this is possible. Maybe I have not properly understood what it is meant there (?)

Comment: An additional condition would help - for example monotonicity of the convergence (the sequence $f_n(x)$ is monotonically increasing or decreasing for every $x$).

Comment: As I have just added on my question by editing, I am told that $f_N$ is continuous for every $N\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: That’s not sufficient, as you can see in my counterexample.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry but I also forgot another (maybe important) detail I have just added. That is, $f_N$ converges to $f$ **in $L^2$ sense**

Comment: Then my counterexample is not valid but the statement is even more false, because $L^2$ convergence only implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, right..and if I suppose I were able to show that a subsequence of $(f_N)$ uniformly converges to $f$, would be this enough to show that $f$ is continuous? @Benjamin

Comment: Yes. Uniform convergence preserves continuity, so if the subsequence is continuous, so is the limit. This is, however, a completely different question. ;-)

Comment: You are right, sorry for the mess and thank you a lot